# Sort A HTML Table In Descending Order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML table which reads data from my DB but the enteries in the DB are not in order, how do i order my 'Stock' column so that they are in alphibetical order (A-Z)

My HTML for my table is below

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
      <tr>
          <th style="padding-right: 10px;">Stock</th>
          <th style="width: 7%; padding-right: 10px;">SEDOL</th>
          <th style="width: 7%; padding-right: 10px;">Quantity</th>
          <th style="width: 7%; padding-right: 10px;">Value</th>
          <th style="width: 15%;" class="text-center">Actions</th>
     </tr>
     <% foreach (var stck in stocks) {%>
     <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle"><%: stck.StockName%></td>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle"><%: stck.SEDOL%></td>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle"><%: stck.Quantity%></td>
          <td class="text-right" style="vertical-align: middle"><%: String.Format("{0:c}", stck.value)%></td>
          <td class="text-right">
               <%if (disinvestments.Find(x => x.Stock == stck.StockName) != null) {%>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" disabled id="create_<%: stck.StockName%>" onclick="SetupDisinvestmentsFields(this,'<%=stck.SEDOL%>','<%=stck.Quantity%>','<%=stck.value%>')">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Create
               </button>
               <%} else {%>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="create_<%: stck.StockName%>" onclick="SetupDisinvestmentsFields(this,'<%=stck.SEDOL%>','<%=stck.Quantity%>','<%=stck.value%>')">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Create
               </button>
               <%} %>
          </td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
```

Can this be done in JavaScript, JQuery, HTML, i'm not sure whats the best way to this hence my question

P.S. I dont want to have to change the table to a `webgrid` or `datatable`.

Comment: you need to provide the rendered html... Not this one..

Comment: Apparently you use smarty (and so php). Why not sorting in php ?

Comment: [list.js is good for front-end sorting](http://www.listjs.com)

Comment: @royhowie - There's no need for a plugin! It can be done with a simple `order by COLLUMN DESC` at the end of your query.

Comment: @James111 unless you want the user to be able to click columns to sort the data accordingly, which is potentially much faster than repeatedly querying the database.

Comment: @royhowie - Yes that's true!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so what you would need to do is actually add an `order by Stockname DESC` at the end of your query.

Comment: I never even thought of this one, stupid i no.  Must have had a brain fart lol.  So much easier this way

Comment: Haha! Yeah that tends to happen from time to time :) Some things you think you're suppose to do with PHP you can do in your SQL query, to an extent of course!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not simply write it in DB Query?

I mean something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <sequence> ORDER BY <parameter to order> ASC"
```

Comment: don't take it personally. lot of peeps here just dump on people

Answer (score 1):

As there are many answers suggest order this at server-side(Me too), if you insist to sort it by javascript/ jquery:

1. Get all rows except first, as its a title row.
2. Detach from table, and covert to `array`
3. Sort by its `Name` column's text.
4. Append back to table.

```js
var rows = $('table tr:not(:first)').detach().toArray();
rows.sort(function(rowA, rowB) {
    var textA = $(rowA).find('td:first').text();
    var textB = $(rowB).find('td:first').text();
    console.log(textA, textB);
    return textA < textB ? -1 : 1;
});

$('table').append(rows);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped">
      <tr>
          <th style="padding-right: 10px;">Stock</th>
          <th style="width: 7%; padding-right: 10px;">SEDOL</th>
          <th style="width: 7%; padding-right: 10px;">Quantity</th>
          <th style="width: 7%; padding-right: 10px;">Value</th>
     </tr>
      <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle">CCC</td>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle">5</td>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle">6</td>
          <td class="text-right" style="vertical-align: middle">3</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle">AAA</td>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle">1</td>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle">2</td>
          <td class="text-right" style="vertical-align: middle">3</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle">BBB</td>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle">3</td>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle">4</td>
          <td class="text-right" style="vertical-align: middle">3</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle">ABC</td>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle">1</td>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle">2</td>
          <td class="text-right" style="vertical-align: middle">3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> you need to add Order clause when you are fetching data from database

```
select * from Table_Name order by Column_Name asc   // for accending order

select * from Table_Name order by Column_Name  desc   // for decending order
```

Comment: now you will be having records in order no need to do any thing in javascript

Answer (score 0):

2 ways i can think of:

- collect your data ordered (ORDER BY - DESC or ASC in your DB)
- use a table plugin that can do that for you. [Datatables](https://www.datatables.net/) plugin worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use "order by columnName desc" in you select statement , because of the sorting of table data will affect the performance of your code